# Applying own function with different parameters to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

i have a problem with apllying my function to a columns in dataframe.
I would like to calculate list of functions to a column in data frame (f.e. sum, mean, max, min) in different time windows (f.e. 3 months, 6 months etc). I wrote a function with parameters:
x - data
w - window 
FUN - function to calculate

```
moving_fun <- function(x, w , FUN , NAs = F, ...) {
  if (w < 1) {
    stop("w parameter must be > 0")
  }
  output <- x
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    lower_bound <- i - w + 1
    if (lower_bound < 1) {
        output[i] <- FUN(x[1:i, ...])
    } else {
      output[i] <- FUN(x[lower_bound:i, ...])
    }
  }
  output
}
```

Im trying to avoid loops for diffrent w and FUN parameters. Data set is over 1.5 mln records and like 40 columns to calculate, I read that loops can be not efficent.

I trying doing it with apply/sapply/mapply functions - is it possible? I dont know how to execute this functions with multiple parameters. How to do this?

I'm trying something like this:

```
sapply(dataForFun$BALANCE_AMT, function(x) {moving_fun(dataForFun$BALANCE_AMT, w = 3 , FUN = sum)})
```

Code for data below. I calculate 3 month averges, grouped per customer, arranged by months ascending. If its first month of customer then mean is calculated only for this month, then for two, and then its moving averge for 3 month window:

```
structure(list(CST_ID = c(345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 
345, 345, 345, 345, 1345, 1345, 1345, 1345, 1345, 1345, 1345, 
1345, 1345, 1345, 1345, 1345), MONTH_LAST_DATE = structure(c(1556582400, 
1559260800, 1561852800, 1564531200, 1567209600, 1569801600, 1572480000, 
1575072000, 1577750400, 1580428800, 1582934400, 1556582400, 1559260800, 
1561852800, 1564531200, 1567209600, 1569801600, 1572480000, 1575072000, 
1577750400, 1580428800, 1582934400, 1585612800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), BALANCE_AMT = c(1160.26, 4155.69, 
145.4, 793.41, 626.88, 4387.91, 3287.01, 4864.89, 1232.69, 2137.81, 
442.03, 2372.87, 1766.91, 2319.87, 4966.47, 4914.29, 3829.45, 
3880.91, 2010.24, 3145.31, 3864.87, 4917.15, 3392.6), MEAN_3MON_PER_CST = c(1160.26, 
2657.975, 1820.45, 1698.16666666667, 521.896666666667, 1936.06666666667, 
2767.26666666667, 4179.93666666667, 3128.19666666667, 2745.13, 
1270.84333333333, 2372.87, 2069.89, 2153.21666666667, 3017.75, 
4066.87666666667, 4570.07, 4208.21666666667, 3240.2, 3012.15333333333, 
3006.80666666667, 3975.77666666667, 4058.20666666667)), .Names = c("CST_ID", 
"MONTH_LAST_DATE", "BALANCE_AMT", "MEAN_3MON_PER_CST"), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Are you grouping by `CST_ID`?  If it is not and you want rolling function, use `rollapply` from `zoo`.   `lapply(list(c("mean", "sum"), function(x) rollapply(dataForFun$BALANCE_AMT, 3, FUN = x))`

Comment: finally yes, but at this moment I stopped on the problem described above. If you think that I should group before, I listen to it

Comment: One real problem with the image is that it is difficult for others to test it.  It may be good if you can get the `dput` of the example showed and edit it in the post along with the expected output.

Comment: *"I read that loops can be not efficent"* is not necessarily accurate. Internally many of the `apply` family are implemented as `for` loops. The inefficiency is typically based on `for` loops *in place of vectorized code*. If you are vectorizing, there is not necessarily significant loss of performance with `for` loops.

Comment: @r2evans i havent even tried for loops, maybe i should

Comment: @akrun rollapply doesnt give what i want, but thanks to you i found 

`rollapplyr(dataForFun$BALANCE_AMT, 3, FUN = sum, partial = T)`